# regex to parse image

Tags: regex

If I have a string in the form:

> data:image/x-icon;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAABmJLR0QAAAAAAAD5Q7t/AAAA2UlEQVQ4y8WSvQvCMBDFX2rFUvuFSAUFBQfBwUXQVfFfFpzdRV2c7O5UKmihX9E6RZo2pXbyTbmX3C+5uwD/FskG+76WsvX65n/3Lm0pdU214HOAbHIWwvzeYPL1p4cT4QCi5DIxEINIdWt+Hs9cXAtg3UOkIJAUpT5ADiho8kbD0NG0LB6Q76xIevwCpW+0bBvj7Y5wgCpI148RBxTmYo7Z1RGPkSk/kc4jgme0oHoJlmFUOC+8lUEMN0ASvyBpGha++IXCJrJyKJGhjIalyZVyNqufP9j/9AH0S0vqrU+YMgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

What is the best regex I can use to parse these elements in an array? (so I can write away the correct image)

update: i understand base64 encoding but the question is actually how to parse these kind of embedded icons in webpages. since i dont know if people are using e.g. base62 ... or other image strings or even other formats to embed images. etc... i also see examples in pages where the identifier is image/x-icon but he string actually contains a png.

**UPDATE** just some giveback to share the code where I used this: http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-favicons/trunk/filters/search/filter_extract_from_page.php

Though I still have some questions e.g. IF only base64 is used etc... but time will tell in practice.

Comment: What would be the expected output in this case?

Comment: I grab the link of icon / shortcut icon from webpages. sometimes its a href url sometimes data. if it is data then it can probably contain a lot of different stuff over all possible websites so with a regex to cover as much conditions e.g. spaces, mistakes, weird image formats or parameters unknown that should make the webscraper better

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you see the `base64` at the beginning? You don't need regex. You need to decode this base64 string into a byte stream and then save it as an image.

I have now saved the following text into a file `icon.txt`:

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAABmJLR0QAAAAAAAD5Q7t
/AAAA2UlEQVQ4y8WSvQvCMBDFX2rFUvuFSAUFBQfBwUXQVfFfFpzdRV2c7O5UKmihX9E6RZo2pXbyTbmX3C+5uwD
/FskG+76WsvX65n
/3Lm0pdU214HOAbHIWwvzeYPL1p4cT4QCi5DIxEINIdWt+Hs9cXAtg3UOkIJAUpT5ADiho8kbD0NG0LB6Q76xIevwCpW+0bBvj7Y5wgCpI148RBxTmYo7Z1RGPkSk
/kc4jgme0oHoJlmFUOC+8lUEMN0ASvyBpGha++IXCJrJyKJGhjIalyZVyNqufP9j
/9AH0S0vqrU+YMgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

And processed:

```
base64 -d icon.txt > icon.png
```

and it shows a red heart icon, 16x16 pixels.

This is the way you can decode it in the command line. Most programming languages offer good libraries to decode it directly in your program.

**EDIT:** If you use PHP, then have a look at [**base64_decode()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php).

Comment: is an embbeded icon in a /html/head/link[@rel='icon' always in this format?

Comment: @edelwater - This looks like a good way of storing the image, because it needs one less call to the webserver than if you save it in a separate PNG file.

Comment: it is not a good way since not all browser support it. but since im writing a parser... i was wondering if also other formats are used.