# How to decode base64 tag <img src> before (or during) the readfile("mypage.html")

Tags: php, javascript, base64, image

I want to know if it's possible to do something like this:

`readfile(base64_decode_only_img_src_tags("mypage.html"));

I've been looking for a solution but without results. The idea is to change the lines encoded of an html file to his decoded line, for example:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,**iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQAQMAAAAlPW0iAAAABlBMVEW/v7////+Zw/90AAAAEUlEQVQI12P4z8CAFWEX/Q8Afr8P8erzE9cAAAAASUVORK5CYII=**">
```

To:

```
<img src="/path/to/images/image.gif">
```

I know maybe I should parse the code to detect the lines with img src tag and then decode the ** marked part of these lines **, but I don't know how to do it during the readfile.

Thanks in advance.

Just as @mario said, I'm testing his code:

```
 $newhtml = file_get_contents('newhtml.html');

function data_to_img($match) {
    list(, $img, $type, $base64, $end) = $match;
    $bin = base64_decode($base64);
    $md5 = md5($bin);   // generate a new temporary filename
    $fn = "$md5.$type";
    file_exists($fn) or file_put_contents($fn, $bin);

    return "$img$fn$end";  // new <img> tag
}
```

If I try to echo:

```
 echo preg_replace_callbak('#(<img[^>]+src=")data:image/(gif|png|jpeg);base64,([\w=+/]+)("[^>]*>)#', "data_to_img", $content);
```

And it worked with the html example above!! Now I'm trying with my real html file. I noticed that the img src are longer than the example that I've provided. Real example of img src that I have is too long to paste here, so please second button mouse click on the dog image and image information to see the base64 code. Thanks a lot!!

[html file with base64 images](http://veterinariavirtual.uab.cat/PRUEBASFULL/noufull.html)

**UPDATE:** Hope this guy had the same problem with base64 large codification and regex

[Link to the similiar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967612/regex-to-parse-image)

**UPDATE2:** Mario solved my problem, thank you very much man. Here's the code and regex for preg_replace_callback:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('#(<img\s(?>(?!src=)[^>])*?src=")data:image/(gif|png|jpeg);base64,([\w=+/]++)("[^>]*>)#', "data_to_img", $content);
```

Comment: Why not just use the actual image?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Are you trying to make it so the client can read an image from an encoded URI?  Are you trying to open the image server-side?  Or do you just want the decoded URI server-side?

Comment: Decode the image, save in your path, point to your path

Comment: I'm trying to open an html file in a textarea (html editor web application), but the browser crashes. I think the problem comes from open images coded in base64 (too large img src) because if I add other images stored at the server it works well. I want to decode the base64 lines to reduce the lenght of the links. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that. But it kind of defeats the purpose, and you would have to take care not to unpack images twice into the temporary directory (which this would imply).

```
echo preg_replace_callback('#(<img\s(?>(?!src=)[^>])*?src=")data:image/(gif|png|jpeg);base64,([\w=+/]++)("[^>]*>)#', "data_to_img", $content);

function data_to_img($match) {
    list(, $img, $type, $base64, $end) = $match;

    $bin = base64_decode($base64);
    $md5 = md5($bin);   // generate a new temporary filename
    $fn = "tmp/img/$md5.$type";
    file_exists($fn) or file_put_contents($fn, $bin);

    return "$img$fn$end";  // new <img> tag
}
```

(I've ignored the invalid `**` markup here.)

In particular you can't combine that with [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile), as you need to capture the file contents yourself to rewrite it. And then it's still a task that should be applied beforehand, not ad-hoc on each request.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm trying!

Comment: Your code seems useful, but there must be a mistake that I can't find.. maybe at pattern '#(<img[^>]+src=")data:image/(gif|png|jpeg);base64,([\w=]+)("[^>]*>)#'. I'll take a look tomorrow.

Thanks again!!

Comment: In case you get an error message, say so. The function name should be `..._callback`.

Comment: Thanks! I added the test results to the question section. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Changed regex. And use `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: Still doesn't work.. seems like the function call **data_to_img** is incorrect or not making a call, but looking at php.net manual an everything looks good. No error reporting and if I do an echo inside the data_to_img function, shows nothing.

echo preg_replace_callback('#(<img[^>]+src=")data:image/(gif|png|jpeg);base64,([\w=+/]+)("[^>]*>)#', **"data_to_img"**, $content);

I think I owe you a beer!

Comment: Hmm, I can't tell. Tried above code, and (apart from the missing semicolon) it worked with your example html as expected. Did you use `$newhtml` instead of `$content`. Otherwise `preg_replace_*` not returning anything from the original source indicates a lower level failure. You should try an updated PHP or libPCRE.

Comment: I'm sorry, It's true!! the code is working with the example I wrote. I realized that every img src from html code is larger than my example. Perhaps the reason why it does not work is that the base64 url image contains directories? Let me give a real example to the question section. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm trying to decode the img src, but maybe the base64 code it's too large to work with it? mmm..

Comment: @JBoY: Edited. But only because it was interesting.

Answer (score 0):

load the readfile result into a variable and use this Regex

`data:image/png;base64,\*\*(.+?)\*\*`

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm trying!