# How to save an image file with the src i have created by drawing on HTML 5 canvas

Tags: php, javascript, image, html, html5-canvas

I have used HTML 5 canvas for drawing something on it using javascript after i have done with drawing i have to save that canvas in hard disk. I can obtain the image src by using the following method:

```
var img = canvas.toDataURL();
```

after this the img variable contains something like the following value

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAfQAAABkCAYAAABwx8J9AAAP/UlEQVR4Xu2dX4wV1R3HZwSCkbWIRpA+UMqfatwArqyKVSMUbENbGx8KafvQxDaRYKMvbdPyxPWlaNK+1FSDD/WptsEXUkWaytY1aK2y65YlS1SQrDR2Xa2KZTEQwNvvb51LLtvdvXPnnjt/znxucjJ3984553c+5zfznd+cM2fCgA8EIAABCEAAAoUnEB............

I can use this image src like

```
<img id=myimage" src=img />
```

and the image gets displayed perfectly in a web browser.

What i want to do is save this image on the hard disk. Is there any way to save it with PHP or javascript.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `$file=base64_decode(<src-with-"data:image/png;base64,"-part-stripped-out>)` like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308996/how-to-decode-base64-tag-img-src-before-or-during-the-readfilemypage-html)

Comment: I think this will help - http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/

Comment: could try file_put_contents( base64_decode('iVBORw...')  );

Comment: And you can actually use the [`data://`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php) way to obtain file from a data URI in PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For PHP >=5.2.0, you can use the `data://` stream wrapper:

```
file_put_contents("file.png",file_get_contents("data://".$var_containing_the_data_uri));
```

where `$var_containing_the_data_uri` should be replaced by the variable containing the data URI, for example `$_POST['image']`.

You could send the data using AJAX post. If you use GET method beware of the URL length limit.

Or if you want to let the clients download/save the image, just create an `<img>` element with the data URI `src` and tell the client to Right-click and save it. You can also refer to the link that @Kode-Plus stated.

Comment: I am using PHP 5.2.0 and your answer is very helpful for me. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have done this recently and here is the code.

HTML Code:

```
<form id="frm" method="post" action="php/saveimg.php" style="display:none">
<input type="submit"  value="submit"/>
<textarea name="data" id="data"></textarea>
</form>
```

JS code: Here "saveimg" is a button in my html.

```
$("#saveimg").click(function(){
var dataurl=document.getElementById('mycanvas').toDataURL();
$("#data").val(dataurl);
$("#frm").trigger("submit");
});
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['data'];
//removing the "data:image/png;base64," part
$uri =  substr($data,strpos($data,",")+1);
file_put_contents('wow.png', base64_decode($uri));
if(file_exists('wow.png')){
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="wow.png"');
readfile('wow.png');
}
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can send the data to server via a form.
For example:

```
var img = canvas.toDataURL();
// store in (hidden) element of a form
document.forms["storeImgForm"].elements["imgSrc"].value = img;
document.forms["storeImgForm"].submit();


<form action="http://www.example.com/storeme.php" Method="POST" name="storeImgForm">
 <input type="hidden" name="imgSrc" value="">
</form>
```

And from PHP pick it up from $_POST["imgSrc"];

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = canvas.toDataURL().split(",")[1],
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;

xhr.open( "POST", "file.php", true );
xhr.send(data);
```

PHP:

```
file_put_contents( "somefile.png", base64_decode( file_get_contents( "php://input" ) );
```